# Span Columns over multiple pages

Tags: two-column, multicol, columns, columnbreak

I'm trying to use the `multicol` package to split my text in two columns. Now I want to put a text in the left column, and another text in the right column. If either column is too long for one page, it should continue on the next page. However, the code I use will push the next column to the next page instead.

Sample code:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
Text for first column...

\columnbreak

Text for second column...
\end{multicols}
```

Which would result in:

L | L (page 1)

R | R (page 2)

if the L column cannot fit on one page.

I would want to have:

L | R

L | R

Can someone help me? Sorry for the bad formatting, it's the first time I ask a question here. If it is not clear what I want, please ask and I'll try to explain.

Best regards,
Aaron

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've deleted the `[multicolumn]` tag since it's reserved for multicolumns in tables

Comment: Perhaps the `paracol` package is an option?

Comment: `multicol` is not what you want, that is a single text flow from one column to the next.

Answer (score 7):

This uses basically the `paracol` package which provides for parallel setting and easy switching of columns. Longer column content is maintained in the corresponding column(s) of the next page(s) (See the red and blue text to demonstrate this)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\raggedright
\textcolor{red}{\blindtext}
\switchcolumn
\raggedleft
\textcolor{blue}{%
\blindtext[3]
}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]