# multicol line spacing

Tags: line-spacing, multicol

I started to work on semi-automated newspaper design. There is some achievement but there is one main bug that I struggle with.

In `multicol` environment the lines of the columns are not aligned across columns. A newspaper looks much better when the lines are on the same level.
The problem: Sometimes it works, sometimes not. I don't know why. It does not make sense to have an MWE, because in the MWE it works. I need help on the doc directly.

Two things mess up line spacing:

1. floats inside the multicol
2. subsections or resp. my own command for subsections

I would tremendously appreciate any help on the latex newspaper project. 
The files are here: 
https://piquestions.com/papersample.tar.gz

Here a sample. The problem is visible in the third column: the picture messes up the alignment, the baselines left and right of the third column are not on the same level.
[image: non-aligned columns in multicol]

Comment: You might have a look on the `\columnbreak` command for explicit vertical 'alignment` and the `paracol` package. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229549/span-columns-over-multiple-pages

Comment: assuming you don't stick $x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}$ into ypur lines, they will all be the same height, but you need to avoid stretchy glue elsewhere, ie make sure between paragraphs or above and below display math and lists the glue is not stretchy

Comment: I asked the same question here: \columnbreak will just break the column, \medskip or esle did not help either. See here for the discussion some time ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216124/includegraphics-space-after-picture-in-multicol-environment

Comment: @user30424 I am not sure what you mean by `\medskip` did not help , by default `\medskip` is stretchy so that is exactly the problem that you must _avoid_ such commands.

Comment: Read the link, it is all there.

Comment: @user30424: They talk of `\medbreak`, not `\medskip`

Comment: yes, I used  \medbreak before and after, still the mess.